# Getting value in openERP Edit form view

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have selection field in the form

```
 <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" widget="selection"/>
```

I have to pass the value selected in the selection field in domain filter as **company_id** in below

```
<tree string="Components" editable="bottom">
       <field name="product_id" context="{'default_supply_method':'produce'}" on_change="onchange_product_id(product_id, name)" domain="[('company_id','=',**company_id**),('stage','=','confirmed')]" />                                        
</tree>
```

Now ,  I need to pass value of field with name `company_id` into the domain with field `product_id`

Help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the field 'company_id' that is saved on form view, you need to add this field on your tree view definition and if you don't need to see it on tree view, put invisible="1" in xml definition.

```
<tree string="Components" editable="botton">
    <field name="company_id" invisible="1" />
    <field name="product_id" context="{'default_supply_method':'produce'}" on_change="onchange_product_id(product_id, name)" domain="[('company_id','=',**company_id**),('stage','=','confirmed')]" />
</tree>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Quentin .  It is working fine.  But What I need is , We have configured multi company.   If I am creating the Purchase Order,  the product lineitems showing product from all the companies.  So, I am trying to filter it in product domain once the company on PO is selected.  Hope, I am clear.